# Unable to print the date in karate framework

Tags: database, karate

Output from dB stored in a variable is 
[{“dateTime”:2019-12-04 11:12:34.34}]
when I tried to define it to a variable 
 * def output= result[0].dateTime
* print output 
Result of the karate execution is 
output= (..???..)

Iam using the dbUtil for fetching the dB record

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes in the result you shared appear to be unicode and that might be the reason. Change the quotes to ascii and it returns the date fine.

Sample Code:

```
Feature: Validation

Scenario:

* def result = [{“dateTime”:2019-12-04 11:12:34.34}]
* string output = result[0]
* print output 
# {"\u201CdateTime\u201D":"2019-12-04 11:12:34.34"}

* def result = [{"dateTime":2019-12-04 11:12:34.34}]
* def output = result[0].dateTime
* print output 
# 2019-12-04 11:12:34.34
```